# Devexpress repositoryItemlookupedit add new row

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I have a devexpress `Grid` with `GridView` and there is the possibility to add new rows to the grid. But one of the columns is a `RepositoryItemLookupEdit` and when there needs to entered a new value it looks to the current values so the casing does not keep like it is typed.

For example: we have employees that work for firm 'Be care' and now I want to add a new employee which is working for the firm 'BEE'. When I try to type 'BEE' in the firm field it will find 'Be care' and thus make it 'BeE'. We would like to keep it like we type it because it is not always easy to tell people how to work around this issue (which is possible by typing 'BeEE' and then delete the 'e').

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do. You just need to handle the special event: ProcessNewValue. This event allows you to catch the moment when a new value is accepted, an add this value to the list, if required.

Comment: But that event is catched only when the complete new value is entered and indeed adds the new value to the list. But our problem is that while typing the list gets called and so our casing is not like we want it.

Comment: As far as I remember, you need to play with the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.SearchMode property. Here are described possible values: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsSearchModeEnumtopic

Comment: Thx for the answer Uranus but now that I want to try it out I notice that we use a RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit and that does not support the SearchMode so I'll need to look further on that one.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Yes, RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit does not has the SearchMode property. The only proprety I know that can control the pop-up window behavior is the ImmediatePopup proeprty: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPopupBaseAutoSearchEdit_ImmediatePopuptopic

Comment: Solved it by setting AutoComplete to false in some cases or with an app.config setting